# Modelagem de Dados - Entidade Fraca

Tags: modelagem

Olá estou estudando sobre Modelagem de Dados e fiquei com dúvida sobre o conceito de Entidade Fraca.

Eu já entendi o que é Entidade Fraca, que é uma entidade que precisa de chaves de outras entidades em que se relacionam para então formar sua chave composta.

Porém, no livro de Modelagem de Dados do professor Carlos Alberto Heuser, diz que o conceito 'entidade fraca' não é adequado porque essa mesma Entidade pode ser relevante em relação a outra Entidade.

Então, o que devo considerar sobre Entidade Fraca? Na prática usamos esse conceito?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi corretamente, o professor deu uma **outra** visão do que é uma entidade fraca.

Normalmente definimos se uma entidade é fraca ou forte olhando **apenas** para ela mesma, mas pelo que entendi o professor entende que alguém pode estar usando a entidade supostamente fraca como chave, então ela deixaria de ser fraca. Faz sentido para mim.

Na prática, como desenvolvedor, eu nunca modelei minhas tabelas sob este conceito e nunca vi alguém (nem DBAs) usar ou citar este conceito para tal.